# SIGABRT error when trying to open a new page in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to test my app but when I test it on the simulator or on an actual device I get it to start the app up the the level select page, however, when I try to tap on the level, I get the error *Thread 1: Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT".* I get this error on my code for the transition style, and when I try to delete the transition the app still gets the error but in a different spot.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?  Here is my code:

MainViewController.h

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "MediumViewController.h"
#import "HardViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, MediumViewControllerDelegate, HardViewControllerDelegate> {
    UIButton *buttonEasy;
    UIButton *buttonMedium;
    UIButton *buttonHard;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonEasy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonMedium;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonHard;

- (IBAction)showEasy:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showMedium:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showHard:(id)sender;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize buttonEasy;
@synthesize buttonMedium;
@synthesize buttonHard;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)MediumViewControllerDidFinish:(MediumViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)HardViewControllerDidFinish:(HardViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showEasy:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}

- (IBAction)showMedium:(id)sender
{
    MediumViewController *controller = [[MediumViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"MediumViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}

- (IBAction)showHard:(id)sender
{
    HardViewController *controller = [[HardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HardViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

Comment: Is there no other error description or stack trace in the debugger console?

Comment: Also, at what line(s) is the `SIGABRT` indicated?

Comment: Yeah is hard to say without some context, add the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you double check the names of your NIB files, I had a similar experience before and discovered I had misspelled the NIB file name.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, thank you.  I forgot a letter in all of them, not sure how I missed it before

Comment: Awesome!  I'd love it if you mark me as the answer -- click the checkmark under the up/down arrows :)

Answer (score 0):

IF there isn't more information in the debugger console, try enabling zombies as that will tell you if there is a memory issues: to enable zombies (Xcode 4) Click Product > Edit Scheme > Run (project Name) > Environment variables add: NSZombieEnabled. Then YES in the value field. Clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check your IB connections. If you had linked an Outlet and then change its name or something it would crash